# How to get the back end data?

Tags: php, reactjs

**LogIn.js**

```
export const logIn = (id, email, password) => {
return (dispatch) => {
    const config = {
        method: 'post',
        url: 'http://localhost/cup/u_select_info.php',
        body: JSON.stringify({
            id: id,
            email: email,
            password: password
        })
    };
    axios.request(config)
        .then((res) => {
            return res.json()
        })
        .then((responseJson) => {
            alert(responseJson);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        })
}}
```

**server**

```
 <?php
include("./conn.php");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://localhost:3000");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type,Access-Control-Allow-Headers, X-Requested-With");

$json = file_get_contents("php://input");
$obj = json_decode($json, true);

$id = $obj['id'];
$email = $obj['email'];
$password = $obj['password'];

if (isset($json) && !empty($json)) {

    $sql = "select * from u_info where id='$id' and email='$email' ";

    $insert_query = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($insert_query->num_rows !== 0) {
        echo json_encode('wrong');
    } else {
        echo json_encode('ok');
    }
} else {
    echo json_encode('try again');
}
```

When I clicked my login button the dev tools told me that

[image]

Also the network response

[image]

Why the back end message "try again" can not show my front page?

Comment: Try removing `.then((res) => {return res.json()})`

Comment: removing this code, my front page alert [object Object] @Toxnyc

Comment: `alert` does not parse JSON objects, have you tried console.log?

Comment: yeah, I just tried console.log , I got some data, but I want to show the message on my front page.

Comment: What data did you get from the console.log?

Comment: {data: "Connection successfully"try again"", status: 200, statusText: "OK", headers: {…}, config: {…}, …}
config:
adapter: ƒ xhrAdapter(config)
body: "{"id":"adad","email":"asasd@qq.com","password":""}"
data: undefined
headers: {Accept: "application/json, text/plain, */*"}
maxContentLength: -1
method: "post"

Comment: So you would use `alert(responseJson.data);` to obtain your backend data instead of `alert(responseJson);`

Comment: yeah, that's right! but I want to alert "ok" on my front page, but the server can not response JSON data

Answer (score 0):

```
if (isset($json) && !empty($json))
```

This if statement isen't possible, the two conditions contradict each other.

Try with this if statement:

```
<?php
include("./conn.php");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://localhost:3000");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type,Access-Control-Allow-Headers, X-Requested-With");

$json = file_get_contents("php://input");
$obj = json_decode($json, true);

$id = $obj['id'];
$email = $obj['email'];
$password = $obj['password'];

if (!empty($json)) {

    $sql = "select * from u_info where id='$id' and email='$email' ";

    $insert_query = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($insert_query->num_rows !== 0) {
        echo json_encode('wrong');
    } else {
        echo json_encode('ok');
    }
} else {
    echo json_encode('try again');
}
```

> That means empty() is essentially the concise equivalent to
> !isset($var) || $var == false.
> https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php#refsect1-function.empty-parameters

Comment: I tried that but it still response "try again ". I think it means my $json is empty. Right?